# Pig ToDate casting error

Tags: date, apache-pig, to-date

I have a date field that I am trying to cast as 'ToDate' via
The dates look like this

```
2015-03-28@18:21:18.

ToDate(REPLACE(REPLACE(Date_Time, '@', ' '),'.',''),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
```

The job dies and gives me this error;  Backend error : Invalid format: ""

I already have filters that take care of NULL values, as well as SIZE > 0 for blanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return type of ToDate function is DateTime object. You need NOT replace @, . characters with '' (space).

Ref : http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/func.html#to-date, for details

**Input : a.csv**

```
 2015-03-28@18:21:18.
```

**Pig Scirpt :**

```
  A = LOAD 'a.csv' AS (dateValue:chararray);
  B = FOREACH A GENERATE ToDate(dateValue,'yyyy-MM-dd@HH:mm:ss.');
  DUMP B;
```

**Output :**

```
    (2015-03-28T18:21:18.000-07:00)
```

We also have an overloaded ToDate function, where we can specify the timezone.

For eg : specifying timezone to GMT

```
  B = FOREACH A GENERATE ToDate(dateValue,'yyyy-MM-dd@HH:mm:ss.','GMT');
  DUMP B;
```

**Output 2:**

```
 (2015-03-28T18:21:18.000Z)
```